# AngularJS: $watch from controller for changes in properties created with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

How do you listen in an angular controller to changes in a child properties? And from that controller know which child was changed?

HTML

```
<div ng-app ng-init='people = [{name: "bill", age: "11"}, {name: "jim", age: ""}, {name: "ryan", age: ""}]'>
  <h1> msg: {{ msg }} </h1>
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat='person in people'>
      <td>
        {{ person.name }}
        <input ng-model='person.name'>      
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

*edit*

For instance, if I wanted to add `.highlight` class to every `<td>` that has a value for age how would I do that? I am new to Angular, but I think $watch would be the right way to do this? Because the value might be changed in the UI but changes could come from elsewhere. 
The parent controller would need the value changed, and pinpoint which one changed and add the class.

Comment: I would recommend using `ng-if`. angular already added `$watch` for your people model, if you use `ng-class` it will add more `$watches`. `ng-if` will not add `$watches`. since your `ng-repeat` loop through the array, adding one if statement does not impact much. but of course you can compare them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when deep $watch is needed, but not for the entire object, you can strip out irrelevant data, this way you make the comparison much faster.

**Example:** (solution by [Karl Seamon](https://plus.google.com/110763473937793578252/posts))

```
  $scope.$watch(function($scope) {
      return $scope.people.
          map(function(obj) {
            return obj.name
          });
}, function (newVal) {
        $scope.msg = 'person name was changed';
    }, true);
```

Live working example: http://jsfiddle.net/choroshin/uhrQ4/

For more information take a look at my blog [post](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/choroshin/2014/01/27/optimizing-large-angularjs-application-karl-seamon/).

Comment: Editing my question. I guess what I am trying to understand is the relationship between the ng-repeat created scope (a child of the $scope in the controller?) and a controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily apply a class based on the person's age as follows:

```
<td ng-class ='{highlight : person.age}'>
```

Angular will do the magic for you, no need to manually watch for changes.

See http://jsfiddle.net/GAQvM/1/

---

EDIT: Old answer on `$scope.$watchCollection`:

It does work when you spell out the actual items to watch:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('[people[0].name, people[1].name, people[2].name]', 
    changeHappened);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rCPvD/

I realise that this is not exactly feasible for large collections, but I think it points out that the watch is shallow, only one level deep.

The documentation for $watchCollection says (my emphasis):

> **Shallow** watches the properties of an object and fires whenever any of
>   the properties change (for arrays, this implies watching the array
>   items; for object maps, this implies watching the properties)

Comment: it has a big impact on the performance, using Karl Seamon's solution you can make watch on a specific property much faster. 
http://jsfiddle.net/choroshin/uhrQ4/